# Vector Calculus - Marsden vs. Apostol

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book for advanced vector calculus. Which one is better? Marsden's Vector Calculus or Apostol's Calculus Vol. II?

Answer (score 0):

I had Marsden's book (ed. 2) as an undergrad in 1978 and I hated it.  In the last decade, I was forced to used the latest editions to teach Vector Calculus and I hated it even more.  My main practical complaint was the dearth of "just plain problems." It seemed like almost every exercise was either "cute" or required some sort of trick or was otherwise tangential to the main thread.

I also didn't find the explanations clear.  It's easy to explain the easy stuff, but this text goes all blurry just at the hardest bits; just when you particularly need clarity.  I recall being very frustrated in 1978 because I couldn't understand some paragraph.  At the time, I thought it was my fault.  Now I know it was just a case of some word salad disguising itself as a paragraph.

Frankly, like most texts, it's written sell the professor.  And many professors will pick up a text and really like it, not realizing that the only reason they like it is that they already know the material, so the explanations seem clear.

I don't have an opinion of the Apostol book, but I've liked some of his other work.